# Sorting lists without resorting to the .sort or sorted function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Given a list of people, in random sequence, I need to write a function that sorts the people and returns a list in order with the older people are at the front of the list. If my input is `[("M" , 23), ("F" , 19), ("M" , 30)]`, my function should return `[("M", 30), ("M", 23), ("F", 19)]`. My function is as follows:

```
def sort_age(lst):
    new_lst=[]
    while lst:
        max_age = lst[0][1]
        oldest = lst[0]
        counter = len(lst)-1
        while counter > 0:
            if lst[counter][1] > max_age:
                max_age = lst[counter][1]
                oldest = lst[counter]
                counter-=1
            lst.remove(oldest)
            new_lst.append(oldest)
    return new_lst
```

Python IDLE throws `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. Where's the error in my code, and how do I correct it?

Comment: Use the buitin `sorted` function: `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`. Also, the combination of `while lst` and `counter = len(lst)-1` while removing elements from `lst` is very problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the builtin `sorted` to avoid reinventing the wheel:

```
lst = [("M" , 23), ("F" , 19), ("M" , 30)]
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

# [('M', 30), ('M', 23), ('F', 19)]
```

But if you wish to write a sort function, then you should rewrite the function to look similar to the following:

```
def sort_by_age(local_lst):
    local_lst = local_lst[:]
    output = []
    while True:
        if len(local_lst) == 0:
            break
        oldest = local_lst[0]
        max_age = oldest[1]
        for tpl in local_lst[:]:
            if tpl[1] > max_age:
                max_age = tpl[1]
                oldest = tpl
        output.append(oldest)
        local_lst.remove(oldest)
    return output

lst = [("M" , 23), ("F" , 19), ("M" , 30)]
print(sort_by_age(lst))

# [('M', 30), ('M', 23), ('F', 19)]
```

One point to help you figure out why the `ValueError` exception is being thrown is mainly that the `.append` and `.remove` operations are being done inside the second `while loop`. This is essentially going to empty the list even before it gets to the second iteration of the first `while loop`. Since the second `while loop` is used to determine what the current `max_age` is, it is best to move the `.append` and `.remove` operations outside the loop so that you are removing the actual max tuple.

The following is the closest to what you started with:

```
def sort_age(lst):
    local_list = lst[:]
    new_lst=[]
    while len(local_list) != 0:
        max_age = local_list[0][1]
        oldest = local_list[0]
        counter = len(local_list)-1
        while counter >= 0:
            if local_list[counter][1] > max_age:
                max_age = local_list[counter][1]
                oldest = local_list[counter]
            counter -= 1
        local_list.remove(oldest)
        new_lst.append(oldest)
    return new_lst
```

Please note that I am copying the original list to make sure the function is returning a new list and not merely emptying the original list.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative response, Abdou. This has helped me to better understand how an appropriate sort function for my issue should be written. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        lst.remove(oldest)
        new_lst.append(oldest)
```

is indented once too much.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16749854)

Comment: He asked for the error in the code and how to correct it. The error is those two lines are indented wrong and the correction is to indent it one less. Nothing else is wrong with the code. No clarification needed. Looks like a copy&paste error.

Comment: In that case, you should flag the question as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. "